# Ytdl-core is not working properly - "Could not find player config"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This error has started occurring on songs that worked perfectly previously.

Error:

```
Error: Could not find player config
at exports.getBasicInfo (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info.js:90:13)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
at async Map.getOrSet (/app/node_modules/ytdl-at async exports.getInfo (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info.js:215:14)
at async Map.getOrSet (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/cache.js:24:19)
at async Object.execute (/app/commands/play.js:59:20)
```

For some reason, if I try the same video multiple times eventually it'll work
but now, it is not working forever on any video i play.

play part:

```js
    const dispatcher = queue.connection
      .play(stream, { type: streamType })
      .on("finish", () => {
        if (collector && !collector.ended) collector.stop();

        if (queue.loop) {
          let lastSong = queue.songs.shift();
          queue.songs.push(lastSong);
          module.exports.play(queue.songs[0], message);
        } else {
          // Recursively play the next song
          queue.songs.shift();
          module.exports.play(queue.songs[0], message);
        }
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        queue.songs.shift();
        module.exports.play(queue.songs[0], message);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue, the problem is that this is currently an ongoing issue for everybody that uses the library, check out the open issue on GitHub for progress [ytdl-core](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/690)

Comment: What library to use temporarily